# Quicksort using function pointers and qsort

Tags: c, function, pointers, quicksort

I have to write a program that uses qsort and function pointers to sort an array of integers.

*Write a program that sorts an array of n integers. After reading n and the values of the array
from the standard input, the program reads a character and if this character is ’a’ then the sorting
should be ascending, if the character is ’d’ then the sorting should be descending and if the
character is ’e’ then the program should quit execution.*

Here is my code, I keep getting the error: `assignment of function 'void qsort(void*, size_t, size_t, int (*)(const void*, const void*))` . Could I please have some feedback? Am I approaching it completely wrong or should I just change a couple of things?

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void quicksort(int *a, int n, int (*func)(char c))
{
    qsort = (a, n, sizeof(int), func);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
}

int compare(char c)
{
    if (c == 'a')
        return -1;
    if (c == 'd')
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
int main()
{
    int *a, n, i;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    a = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    char c;
    while (1)
    {
        scanf("%c", c);
        if (c == 'e')
            break;
        quicksort(a, n, compare);
    }
    free(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `qsort = (a, n, sizeof(int), func);` that tries to assign a value to `qsort`. You are supposed to call the function not change it.

Comment: And the `compare` function signature is wrong. Read the [qsort manual](https://linux.die.net/man/3/qsort) for what it needs to be. That is, your use of `qsort` is not correct. You need to write a compare function that compares two integers and not to compare against fixed values of `a` and `d`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`qsort = (a, n, sizeof(int), func);`

should be

`qsort(a, n, sizeof(int), func);`

i.e., call the function, don't attempt to assign to it.

Also, the compare function you pass to qsort has a different signature, taking two `void*` arguments instead of a single `char`.

Comment: That makes sense, but where should i implement the 'a' and 'd' cases then?
Thank you !

Comment: One way would be to have two compare functions, one for each sorting direction, and pass the corresponding one to `qsort`.

Answer (score -1):

Your code doing re-assignment, not function call.

```
void quicksort(int *a, int n, int (*func)(char c))
{
    qsort(a, n, sizeof(int), func);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
}
```

make call qsort function, and fix func signature get two parameter.